# Distinct Uncountable Dense Subsets of R

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm working on Question #5.v in chapter 3.1 of Sidney Morris's Toplogy without Tears.

I'm supposed to prove that  $\mathbb{R}$ has $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ distinct uncountable dense subsets.

I think my method gets at least halfway there.

Here's what I've done:

Note that $|\mathbb{I}| = |\mathbb{I}^{+}| = \mathfrak{c}$

$\forall\alpha\in \mathbb{I}^{+}, $ let the set $B_\alpha = \{\mathbb{R}^{-}\cup\mathbb{Q}^{+}\cup\{\alpha\}\}$

Then, each $B_\alpha$ is distinct, uncountable, and dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and there are $\mathfrak{c}$ of them indexed to the positive irrationals.

Now, consider that $|P(\mathbb{I}^{+})| = 2^{\mathfrak{c}}$, where each element of the power set is a distinct set of positive irrationals.

Since each element of the power set can be mapped 1-1 to some union of $B_\alpha$'s, we have $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ distinct uncountable dense subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

If this is correct, I have two further questions:

1) My construction identifies $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ of required type of subset.  Am I done?  That is, should I be trying to determine whether there are exactly $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ or more?

2) Is there a cleaner/more elegant way to construct $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ subsets of the required type?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ has only $2^\mathfrak{c}$ subsets in total, because the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathfrak{c}$ by definition.

Comment: This resembles https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2991576.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks, Connor.  I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) My construction identifies $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ of required type of subset.  Am I done?  That is, should I be trying to determine whether there are exactly $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ or more?

$\mathbb{R}$ has $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ subsets. So yeah, there can't be more in the sense of cardinality.

> 2) Is there a cleaner/more elegant way to construct $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ subsets of the required type?

By "required type" you mean "dense"? If not then obviously that totally depends on what "required type" means and it is a case-by-case study.

If yes, then your construction can be simplified: for any subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ the subset $\mathbb{Q}\cup A$ is dense. And $\mathbb{Q}\cup A=\mathbb{Q}\cup B$ if and only if $A=B$ (under the assumption that both $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$). Since $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ is of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ then you're done.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  "Required" for this problem meant "distinct, countable, dense".  Your answer makes sense to me--Thanks!  I think I was trying too hard to explicitly construct an example, when I should have been thinking more about the characteristics of general subsets.

Comment: Do you consider Cassius12 complete @freakish